# Creating and using func pointer to method of friend class

Tags: c++, function, class, pointers, friend

I have 2 classes:

```
enum class Enumtype
{
    typ1,
    typ2,
};

class A
{
private:
    retType Func1(arg1Type, arg2Type, arg3Type);
    retType Func2(arg1Type, arg2Type, arg3Type);
public:
    A();
    retType Func(Enumtype, arg1Type, arg2Type, arg3Type);
}

class B
{
private:
    arg1Type a;
    arg2Type b;
    arg3Type c;
public:
    int FunctionFromB(Enumtype);
}
```

So the primary use was this:

```
int B::FunctionFromB(Enumtype x)
{
    A* objectA;
    for(int i=0; i<whatever; i++)
    {
        objectA->Func(x, a+i, b+(2*i), c+(3*i));
    }
}
retType A::Func(Enumtype x, arg1type a, arg2type b, arg3type c)
{
    switch(x)
    {
    case Enumtype::typ1:
        return Func1(a, b, c);
    case Enumtype::typ2:
        return Func2(a, b, c);
    default:
        return Func1(a, b, c);
    }
}
```

Unfortunately I do not want to run switch every loop and so I thought about this:

- in class A write "friend class B"
- Remove A::Func()
- make function ptr in B::FunctionFromB()
- make switch in B::FunctionFromB(), which initializes mentioned function ptr to either A::Func1 or A::Func2. Switch will resemble the one in A::Func()
- instead of running objectA->Func(x, a, b, c), run objectA->functionPtr(a, b, c)

How to do this? I tried to do this with std::function, but I don't know how to properly declare/initialize/call it to make it work.

**EDIT:**
I've edited FunctionFromB, because I've skipped one important part -> Func was called in loop with different args.

**EDIT2:**
Help was given and I have answer saying how to do this with C-style function ptr, yet I want to make it work with std::function. I made it like that (note that class B and enum are the same):

```
class A
{
private:
    retType Func1(arg1Type, arg2Type, arg3Type);
    retType Func2(arg1Type, arg2Type, arg3Type);
public:
    A();
    typedef std::function<retType(arg1Type, arg2Type, arg3Type)> funcPtr;
}

int B::FunctionFromB(Enumtype typeB)
{
    A* objectA;
    A::funcPtr func = nullptr;

    switch(type)
    {
    case Enumtype::typ2:
        func = std::bind(&A::Func2, objectA, std::placeholders::_1,
                            std::placeholders::_2, std::placeholders::_3);
        break;
    case Enumtype::typ2:
    default:
        func = std::bind(&A::Func1, objectA, std::placeholders::_1,
                            std::placeholders::_2, std::placeholders::_3);
        break;
    }

    for(int i=0; i<whatever; i++)
        func(a+i, b+(2*i), c+(3*i));
}
```

and I guess, it works. If anyone finds an error in here or a better way, please do tell me ;)

Comment: You want to read about *pointers to member functions* e.g. [here](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/pointers-to-members).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you use an unscoped enum for EnumType?

```
enum Enumtype
{
    enumtyp1,
    enumtyp2,
    enumtypmax
};
```

If it is an option, the compiler offers you for free a conversion to int : `enumtyp1 -> 0`, `enumtyp2 -> 1`,`enumtypmax -> 2` (per 3.9.2 § 10 *The value of an enumerator or an object of an unscoped enumeration type is converted to an integer by
integral promotion*)

The values are guaranteed per 3.9.2 §2 *The identifiers in an
enumerator-list are declared as constants, and can appear wherever constants are required. An enumeratordefinition
with = gives the associated enumerator the value indicated by the constant-expression. If the first
enumerator has no initializer, the value of the corresponding constant is zero. An enumerator-definition
without an initializer gives the enumerator the value obtained by increasing the value of the previous enumerator
by one.*

```
enum { a, b, c=0 };
enum { d, e, f=e+2 };
```

*defines a, c, and d to be zero, b and e to be 1, and f to be 3.*

You could then build a static array of A methods in A and use a direct array index that should be simpler than a switch :

```
enum Enumtype
{
    enumtyp1,
    enumtyp2,
    enummax
};

class A
{
private:
    typedef retType (__thiscall A::*funcx)(arg1Type,arg2Type,arg3Type);
    retType Func1(arg1Type, arg2Type, arg3Type);
    retType Func2(arg1Type, arg2Type, arg3Type);
    static funcx fp[enummax];
public:
    A();
    retType Func(Enumtype, arg1Type, arg2Type, arg3Type);
};

class B
{
private:
    arg1Type a;
    arg2Type b;
    arg3Type c;
public:
    int FunctionFromB(Enumtype);
};

int B::FunctionFromB(Enumtype x)
{
    A* objectA;
    for(int i=0; i<whatever; i++)
    {
        objectA->Func(x, a+i, b+(2*i), c+(3*i));
    }
    return whatever;
}
retType A::Func(Enumtype x, arg1Type a, arg2Type b, arg3Type c)
{
    funcx f = A::fp[x];
    return (this->*fp[x])(a, b, c);
}

A::funcx A::fp[enummax] = { &A::Func1, &A::Func2 };
```

---

Alternatively, you could get directly a pointer in `B::FunctionFromB` and directly call it repeatedly :

```
enum Enumtype
{
    enumtyp1,
    enumtyp2,
    enummax
};

class A
{
public:
    typedef retType (__thiscall A::*funcx)(arg1Type,arg2Type,arg3Type);
private:
    retType Func1(arg1Type, arg2Type, arg3Type);
    retType Func2(arg1Type, arg2Type, arg3Type);
    static funcx fp[enummax];
public:
    A();

    friend class B;
};

class B
{
private:
    arg1Type a;
    arg2Type b;
    arg3Type c;
    A::funcx getFunc(Enumtype);
public:
    int FunctionFromB(Enumtype);
};

A::funcx B::getFunc(Enumtype x){
    return A::fp[x];
}

int B::FunctionFromB(Enumtype x)
{
    A* objectA;
    A::funcx funcPtr = getFunc(x);
    for(int i=0; i<whatever; i++)
    {
        (objectA->*funcPtr)(a+i, b+(2*i), c+(3*i));
    }
    return whatever;
}

A::funcx A::fp[enummax] = { &A::Func1, &A::Func2 };
```

In that latter case, you could avoid declaring the array of methods in A, stick to a scoped enum for EnumType and use the switch once per call to `B::FunctionFromB` :

```
A::funcx B::getFunc(Enumtype x){
    switch (x) {
        case EnumType::typ1:
            return &A::Func1;
        case EnumType::typ2:
            return &A::Func2;
        case default:
            return &A::Func1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I will definitely try this ;) Unfortunately I got lotta work today and will be probably able to check this in a 1-2 weeks time. Then I'll comment/answer/mark answer.

Comment: One thing though...can we do it with std::function instead of C-like function type?

Comment: IMHO, std::function will work but would be overkill. Pointer to methods or array of methods is enough *for the current question*.

Comment: This works - just tried. Still I don't like using this: `typedef retType (__thiscall A::*funcx)(arg1Type,arg2Type,arg3Type);` when we have std::function in Cpp. Even if it'd be an overkill, would You be kind enough to show me how to do this? Making pointers to member functions has always been a problem for me :/

Comment: @ForEveR: OP would like to see your answer again - for MKK : ForEveR already posted an answer using std::function and deleted it

Comment: I did it like this: `typedef std::function<retType(arg1, arg2, arg3)> funcType;` and then `funcType funcPtr = std::bind(&A::Func1, objectA, std::placeholder _1, std::placeholder _2, std::placeholder _3);` and at the end I call it like this: `funcPtr(a+i, b+(2*i), c+(3*i));`. Can You find any errors in this?